# Sub-circuit in Altium

Tags: components, schematics, altium

I am working on Altium Designer and I would like to create a subcircuit from existing components. To be more clear, I want to be able to create a new part from a schematic I already draw. For a very simple example, if I draw a capacitor and a resistor in parallel, is there a way for me to create a new component called "RC part" with 1 input and 1 output ?

The goal of this would be to simulate each part of my circuit separately.

I've seen that I can create a new "sub-circuit" but it looks like I can only write it in SPICE and I am not familiar with this.

Comment: Check out also device sheets and snippets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Altium you have to place [ports](http://techdoc.altium.com/display/ADRR/Sch_Obj-Port%28%28Port%29%29_AD) on the schematic of the sub-circuit to define its outputs and inputs.

Example:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Once this schematic is ready and you have defined all of its ports, you should switch to the schematic into which you want to place an instance of this sub-circuit.

Now, select the **Create Sheet Symbol From Sheet or HDL** option from the **Design** menu.

[image]

A list will pop up with your project's schematics, choose the one you want to create a sheet entry (component). A green block will appear with the previously defined port to place.

[image]

If you click on it the corresponding schematic will be shown too. If you later want to redefine or just to add some new ports, you can do that as well. Just update the sub-circuit's sheet and then in the main schematic select the **Synchronize Sheet Entries and Ports** option from the **Design** menu.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that's exactly what I needed.
You helped me a lot on this one.

Comment: Just another quick question : when trying to simulate, Altium often gives me this error message :


External exception EEDFADE at 74E55B68.
KERNELBASE.dll, Base Address: 74E40000.
Exception Occurred In GenerateReport

I don't know how to solve this problem and I couldn't find any solution on the Internet

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with simulations in Altium. Maybe you should ask it in a new question, just make sure to add every detail.